# Javascript confirm on gridview dropdownlist reversed results

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have a drop down list as below:

```
<asp:DropDownList ToolTip="# of Records Per Page" ID="dropDownRecordsPerPage" runat="server" TabIndex="-1" OnInit="dropDownRecordsPerPage_Init" EnableViewState="true"
  AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dropDownRecordsPerPage_SelectedIndexChanged" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
  Style="text-align: left; color: gray;">
  <asp:ListItem Value="10" Text="10" />
  <asp:ListItem Value="25" Text="25" />
  <asp:ListItem Value="50" Text="50" Selected="True" />
  <asp:ListItem Value="100" Text="100" />
  <asp:ListItem Value="100000" Text="All" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

On Page_Load I add:

```
dropDownRecordsPerPage.Attributes.Add("onchange", "if(CheckDirty2()) return true;");
```

My javascript function is:

```
 function CheckDirty2() {
        var dirty = document.getElementById('<%= HiddenFieldDirty.ClientID %>').value;
        if (dirty.toLowerCase() == "yes") {
            return  confirm("Are you SURE you want to do this?");
         };
    };
```

This is working.  Meaning that when the hidden field value is = yes then the confirm message  displays with OK and Cancel.  This is what i want to happen.

I would expect that if the user clicks Ok then the postback continues and if the user click cancel the the postback is canceled.

What is happening is just the opposite.  If the user clicks OK then the postback is canceled.  If they click cancel, the postback continues.

I am sure that I am missing something simple.  I have spend 3+ hours on this one item and I now have myself thoroughly confused.

Any help, with some detail, would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I made changes suggest by @Andrei.  see below:

```
dropDownRecordsPerPage.Attributes.Add("onchange", "if(CheckDirty2()) return false;");
```

Dropdownlist generated HTML:

```
<select style="text-align: left; color: gray;" title="# of Records Per Page" tabindex="-1" 
    id="ctl00_main_dropDownRecordsPerPage" 
    onchange="if(CheckDirty2()) return false;setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$main$dropDownRecordsPerPage\',\'\')', 0)" 
    name="ctl00$main$dropDownRecordsPerPage">

    ...

</select>
```

Same result...click OK postback cancelled.  Click Cancel post back continues.

as an FYI here is my selected index changed code:

```
        if (!checkDropdownSelection()) return;
        DropDownList dropDownRecordsPerPage = (DropDownList)sender;
        int pagerValue = Convert.ToInt32(dropDownRecordsPerPage.SelectedValue);

        gvChargeEntry.PageSize = pagerValue;
        BindGrid();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DropDownList's AutoPostBack is a curious thing. It appends the post back code to the `onchange` code, rather than assigning another handler to the event. So effectively in your case onchange looks like this:

```
if(CheckDirty2()) return true;
__doPostBack(...
```

Obviously when `CheckDirty2` is true, the return happens, code never reaches post back function. And if `CheckDirty2` is false the post back function is called.

To fix this you need to modify condition to something that will return (does not matter what) only if confirmation fails:

```
if(CheckDirty2() == false) return false;
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I have made your suggested changes but same result.  I Edited my post to reflect.

Comment: @GuyNethery, you missed the `!` in `if`. This makes all the difference. Or you can write `if(CheckDirty2() == false)` if you want, the point is *return only if confirmation failed*

Comment: details, details, details.....Curious but when I added the `!` the post back never happened.  I changed it to `if(CheckDirty2() == false)` and it now works as desired.

Comment: @GuyNethery, that's strange. Updated the answer for everyone to see the working version